# Problem with Date.UTC() method in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, methods

Below is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var y2k = new Date(Date.UTC(2000, 0));
   document.write(y2k);
</script>
```

I expect it to show midnight `jan  1 ,2000` but why it show `Fri Dec 31 1999 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)` ???

Comment: It shows `Sat Jan 01 2000 05:45:00 GMT+0545 (IST) ` for me

Comment: it shows the right dateTime converted to local time for both of you :-P

Comment: @guidhouse what does it show for you, I am +0445 GMT

Comment: Sat Jan 1 01:00:00 UTC+0100 2000 as Expected since I live in Copenhagen(UTC+1). 
Your browser is probably not taking summer/winter-time into account and believes you are UTC+0545.

Comment: My best guess is that you are in Nepal where the official clock is set according to daylight saving time. But your computer and/or browser is not taking DST into account:)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well :-)
I guess your browser is at a location with Pacific standard time.
If so the time you have is the first of January 2000 00:00 AM with the subtracted 8 hours from GMT.

Comment: so, Date.UTC() create local time zone??

Comment: No, `new Date()` uses the local time zone.

Comment: No date.UTC(); is the right thing to do, but when you display the date you should use y2k.toUTCString as @Kooilnc writes

Answer (score 1):

I think using `y2k.toUTCString()` will give you the date/time you expect.

Comment: It will :)
I should have added that to my answer.